# how to enter bios/uefi from ubuntu?

Tags: boot, uefi

on windows, there is "advcanced boot" option to enter the uefi/bios. This allowed me to use the "ultra fast boot" feature on my motherboard that skips going through the uefi settings. This makes the boot time lower but I cant access the uefi on startup.

I was wondering if there a way to get to the uefi similarly on ubuntu.

(note: I know removing the cmos battery is an option but I am hoping there can be an easier way to do this)

Comment: Press ESC on boot and select System Settings in grub menu. There may be also another key to directly get ti UEFI. It depends on hardware.

Comment: Technically, you are not entering BIOS from Ubuntu...  You enter BIOS first and then choose the OS (assuming you have more than one) via the `grub` menu.  Thus, how to enter BIOS depends on the manufacturer of your hardware.  What is your manufacturer?  Google for it, with the word "BIOS".  Most likely, you'll find out the key to use to enter it in one of the top hits.  And no, removing the battery won't help...unless you want to reset all of the BIOS settings.

Comment: I have seen both of these in addition to Pilot6's suggestion on using grub menu entry for firmware settings, not sure if one works in different version of Ubuntu or what difference is. Reboot into UEFI:
`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware` or
`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`